# Trying to connect the mySQL database on Railway to the backend of my React App built in Next.js but no data is showing up

Tags: mysql, server

I have linked my local mySQL workbench database to the deployment website "railway" - they are working and connected. If I edit one database the other updates automatically.

However in my app when I try to connect to the database now being hosted on railway my data is not displayed. If I revert to my local database it works fine.

This works okay

```
 const db = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "password",
      database: "flashcards_2.0",
    });

    app.get("/ClassSelector/:yearId/:weekId/:classId", function (req, res) {
  const yearId = req.params.yearId;
  const weekId = req.params.weekId;
  const classId = req.params.classId;

  const q = `SELECT * FROM ${classId} WHERE year = ${yearId} AND week = ${weekId}`;
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    console.log(data);

    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

This is the data I tried with the hosted server

The railway gives me these two pieces of data in relation to the database - I have starred out the password but otherwise it is identical

mysql -hcontainers-us-west-19.railway.app -uroot -pnkEDYn2av******* --port 6177 --protocol=TCP railway

mysql://root:nkEDYn2av*******@containers-us-west-19.railway.app:6177/railway

Here is my code that I swapped in to try and the hosted server

```
  const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "containers-us-west-19.railway.app",
  user: "root",
  password: "nkEDYn2av*********",
  database: "railway",
});
```

[image: This is what my database looks like in mySQL workbench which is linked to railway hosted database]

Answer (score 0):

The axios.get() on the client side was still looking at localhost and not the http of the new hosted website. I thought that fixed it but  didn't.

I still have the same problem –  I still cannot seem to access the database being hosted on railway – but I am getting a new error.

This is my app

https://eb-flashcards.vercel.app/

Here is the link that should retrieve the flashcards I want...

https://ebflashcards.vercel.app/ClassSelector/2022/35/Listening%20Kiso

[image: this is the error I see]